# Get text value from reference not using state

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get a value from TextInput using reference but always it's printing undefined. I don't know why it's happening.

```
 <TextInput 
   ref={value =>this._passwordRef = value }
   style={styles.inputTextStyle} placeholder='Enter password here'>  
    </TextInput>


 <TouchableOpacity onPress={(view)=>{this.onSubmit()}} style={{height:50,borderColor:'#000',borderWidth:2,marginLeft:20,marginRight:20}}>
              <Text style={styles.btnTextStyle}>Submit</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

  onSubmit(){
      console.log(this._passwordRef._lastNativeText);
  }
```

The current version of react is.

"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3"

Answer (score 0):

according to the ReactNative docs it seems there is no ref props for TextInput.

you need to hanlde changing and checking the value of the input using `onChangeText` and `value` . check the below code for better understanding

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const TextInputtt = () => {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');

  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}

export default TextInputtt;
```